# Date Range Query Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Below query when executed in Elasticsearch version 1.x

Was considering documents created after 6/15/2016 that is documents which have time beyond 12 Am for the date 6/15/2016.It was considering documents till 6/15/2016 23:59:59.999 .

But with new version of ES 2.x the range query has stopped considering documents which have time beyond 12 Am for the date 6/15/2016. Now It is considering documents till 6/14/2016 23:59:59.999.

What exactly changed here?

```
{
 "from": 0,
 "size": 10,
 "sort": [
   {
     "PRONumber.sort": {
       "order": "desc"
     }
   }
 ],
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must": [
       {
         "match": {
           "BOLNumber": {
             "query": "7861254",
             "analyzer": "gtz_search_analyzer",
             "operator": "and"
           }
         }
       },
       {
         "range": {
           "CreatedDate": {
             "gte": "1753-01-01",
             "lte": "2016-06-15"
           }
         }
       }
     ]
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, you have to add it inside the `must` section or other boolean sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In elasticsearch 2.x for the  query in the OP the upper-limit is `6/15/2016 00:00:00.000` and not `6/14/2016 23.59.59.999`.
From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#_date_math_and_rounding) it follows that you would need to explictly specify in the query to `round-up` by day as shown in the example below

Example:

```
{
 "from": 0,
 "size": 10,
 "sort": [
   {
     "PRONumber.sort": {
       "order": "desc"
     }
   }
 ],
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must": [
       {
         "match": {
           "BOLNumber": {
             "query": "7861254",
             "analyzer": "gtz_search_analyzer",
             "operator": "and"
           }
         }
       },
       {
         "range": {
           "CreatedDate": {
             "gte": "1753-01-01",
             "lte": "2016-06-15||/d"
           }
         }
       }
     ]
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!. I think earlier in 1.x the upper limit was 6/15/2016 23.59.59.999 not 6/14/2016 23.59.59.999.